# Prevent other application from closing Fiddler

Tags: windows, windows-10

I've one application which to prevent it's analysis kills all applications like browsers, [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) etc. Is there any way to prevent killing of executable?

I thought of running Fiddler in another user account but it is not able to show HTTP headers passing thru different account.

Any solution?

Comment: Depends how it detects it and how it terminates it.  I assume renaming fiddler.exe to Riddler.exe for example doesn't help?  What is the application of out interest?

Comment: Oh ieinspector worked nicely when run from another account.